# Fitting heteroscedastic models using the `gls` function

Tags: r, modeling, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares, irls

Consider the following heteroscedastic model:
$$y_i = f(x_i, \beta) + g(x_i, \theta)\varepsilon_i, i = 1, \ldots, n, \tag{1}$$
where $f(\cdot, \beta)$ is the regression function and $g(\cdot, \theta)$
is the variance function. For simplicity, assume the errors $\{\varepsilon_i\}$ are i.i.d. with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Regarding model $(1)$, I understand (but I am not quite sure) that the `gls` function in `nlme` package can be used (at least when $f$ is linear) to implement the iteratively reweighted least squares algorithm (Carroll, Ruppert, *Transformation and Weighting in Regression*, p. 69). When I read the manual of `nlme`, it looks to me that `gls` function restricts the forms of $g$ to a very small class of functional forms. For example, given observations $\{(y_i, x_{i1}, x_{i2}): i = 1, \ldots, n\}$, is it
possible to use `gls` to fit the following special case of $(1)$:
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2} + \sqrt{\theta_0 + \theta_1 x_{i1}^2 + \theta_2 x_{i2}^2}\varepsilon_i, i = 1, \ldots, n$$
, where $\theta_0 > 0, \theta_1 \geq 0, \theta_2 \geq 0$? If yes, how should I specify my own square-root variance functional form in `gls`? If
no, are there any other available R packages to implement IRLS algorithm?

Comment: First of all, your notation is misleading. It should be something like $y_i = f(x_i, \beta) + \varepsilon_i,\ \varepsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, g(x_i, \theta)\cdot\sigma^2),\ i = 1, \ldots, n$. Then, package nlme does not offer a polynomial variance structure. You can combine variance structures, but it's a multiplicative combination, not additive. Why do you believe that this specific variance structure fits your data? Maybe a combination of the existing `varClasses` can achieve a similar variance structure?

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your response. However, I think my notation is fine since I don't restrict the error to be Gaussian errors. In fact, I am doing a simulation study so this variance structure is just one of various heteroscedastic parts that I am considering. If `nlme` can't fit this model conveniently, I think I will code IRLS by myself.

Comment: No, your notation isn't fine. You can use other distributions, but the point is that you model the variance and not the residuals.

Comment: What makes you think I modeled residuals?